# List Out Of Range (map)

Tags: python, python-3.x

In python 3.7 my list is out of range in a map and I have tried multiple things to fix it. (This is an Oregon Trail game I am making)

Ive Tried changing the max x and max y

```py
trail = [[1 for x in range(maxx)]for y in range(maxy)]
trail [25][2] = "Fort Kearney"
trail [26][2] = "St. Joseph"
trail [24][2] = "Ash Hollow"
trail [22][2] = "Chimney Rock"
trail [22][2] = "Fort Laramie"
trail [29][2] = "Independence Rock"
trail [27][2] = "Fort Bridger"
trail [24][2] = "Sublette Cutoff"
trail [23][2] = "North Platte River Crossing"
trail [23][2] = "Fort Hall"
trail [22][2] = "Snake River Crossing"
```

I am getting the error_

```
/Python/Python37-32/oregontrail.py", line 15, in <module>
    trail [25][2] = "Fort Kearney"
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: What are `maxx` and `maxy`?

Comment: You really need to show `maxx` and `maxy`.  Without them this problem cannot be reproduced.  That having been said, it's quite likely that you've reversed the two.  The way you're using it, the first dimension has size `maxy` and the second has size `maxx`.  Is that really what you intended?

Comment: I found it. I was doing the two things backwards. maxx and maxy are the maximum amount of x and y that the person can creaate.